# CSS grid layout and pre formatting on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I try to move a fairly simple website to a grid layout. The HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<header> ... </header>
<div> ... </div>    
<footer> ... </footer>
</body>
```

The `body` element's children are displayed in rows and, on non-mobile devices, are supposed to be 60em wide:

```
body
{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    gap: 4px;
    max-width: 80em;
}
@media (min-width: 751px)
{
    body > * {
        width: 60em;
        max-width: 60em;
    }
}
```

This works well (on any device) except for pages which contain a paragraph of class `code`, formatted like this:

```
p.code
{
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 1px #333 solid;
    margin: 2em 3em 2em 3em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In this case, the page is displayed much too wide on mobile devices. With my previous (non-grid) design, the `code` paragraphs were rendered properly for small screens (and you had to scroll horizontally for longer lines of code). What can I do to avoid this issue with the grid-based layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think the discrepancy comes from the fact that `751px !- 60em` so I have used that in the media query. I have also modified the media query to involve the body only.
Try this:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 4px;
}

p.code {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  margin: 2em 3em 2em 3em;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 80em) {
  body {
    width: 60em;
    max-width: 60em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at elementum nunc, sed tincidunt massa. Vestibulum rhoncus, libero nec porttitor gravida, orci arcu commodo est, sodales tristique neque eros vulputate mi. Curabitur ac lorem mattis, suscipit
  massa rutrum, suscipit metus. Aenean non leo malesuada, facilisis velit ac, mollis magna. Mauris in magna et leo porta malesuada. Donec blandit mi orci, at lacinia libero facilisis ac. Sed at felis lectus. Quisque et pharetra mi. Praesent vel mi id
  leo condimentum accumsan vitae lobortis nibh. Aliquam quis sapien et libero semper malesuada quis vitae dolor. Sed dapibus consectetur turpis nec tempus. Pellentesque elit erat, dapibus eget gravida quis, commodo at leo. Maecenas non blandit nunc.
</header>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at elementum nunc, sed tincidunt massa. Vestibulum rhoncus, libero nec porttitor gravida, orci arcu commodo est, sodales tristique neque eros vulputate mi. Curabitur ac lorem mattis, suscipit
  massa rutrum, suscipit metus. Aenean non leo malesuada, facilisis velit ac, mollis magna. Mauris in magna et leo porta malesuada. Donec blandit mi orci, at lacinia libero facilisis ac. Sed at felis lectus. Quisque et pharetra mi. Praesent vel mi id
  leo condimentum accumsan vitae lobortis nibh. Aliquam quis sapien et libero semper malesuada quis vitae dolor. Sed dapibus consectetur turpis nec tempus. Pellentesque elit erat, dapibus eget gravida quis, commodo at leo. Maecenas non blandit nunc.</div>
<p class="code">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at elementum nunc, sed tincidunt massa. Vestibulum rhoncus, libero nec porttitor gravida, orci arcu commodo est, sodales tristique neque eros vulputate mi. Curabitur ac lorem mattis, suscipit
  massa rutrum, suscipit metus. Aenean non leo malesuada, facilisis velit ac, mollis magna. Mauris in magna et leo porta malesuada. Donec blandit mi orci, at lacinia libero facilisis ac. Sed at felis lectus. Quisque et pharetra mi. Praesent vel mi id
  leo condimentum accumsan vitae lobortis nibh. Aliquam quis sapien et libero semper malesuada quis vitae dolor. Sed dapibus consectetur turpis nec tempus. Pellentesque elit erat, dapibus eget gravida quis, commodo at leo. Maecenas non blandit nunc.</p>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at elementum nunc, sed tincidunt massa. Vestibulum rhoncus, libero nec porttitor gravida, orci arcu commodo est, sodales tristique neque eros vulputate mi. Curabitur ac lorem mattis, suscipit
  massa rutrum, suscipit metus. Aenean non leo malesuada, facilisis velit ac, mollis magna. Mauris in magna et leo porta malesuada. Donec blandit mi orci, at lacinia libero facilisis ac. Sed at felis lectus. Quisque et pharetra mi. Praesent vel mi id
  leo condimentum accumsan vitae lobortis nibh. Aliquam quis sapien et libero semper malesuada quis vitae dolor. Sed dapibus consectetur turpis nec tempus. Pellentesque elit erat, dapibus eget gravida quis, commodo at leo. Maecenas non blandit nunc.</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this change does not fix the problem, as it addresses devices with larger screens (> 751px / 80em). For mobile devices, the `div` element is still too wide if a code paragraph is present, and the other modification of the media query leads to the content elements (header, div, footer) not being centered anymore on larger screens. For those screens, I want the body to use 100% of the viewport, with its children elements being centered with a width of 60em.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to define width values for the `body` element's children for both large and small screens separately:

```
@media (min-width: 60em)
{
    body > * {
        width: 50em;
        min-width: 30em;
        max-width: 50em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 59em)
{
    body > * {
        width: 20em;
        min-width: 20em;
        max-width: 20em;
    }
```

Thanks again to aabdulahad for his suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

So that `.code` shrink in the `grid` container, set `overflow: auto;` - you already have it.
For `body` to have a width of no more than `80em`, set `max-width: min(60em, 100%);`:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  max-width: min(60em, 100%);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.code{
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  margin: 2em 3em 2em 3em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, architecto officia dignissimos est rem natus voluptates eaque eligendi autem dolores quam quae ducimus eos iusto nulla reprehenderit eum veritatis nostrum!
<p class="code">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, natus ullam veniam ea magni soluta illum ratione libero minima id impedit culpa deleniti consequatur odit eveniet. Iure, dolore temporibus facere.
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, reiciendis exercitationem maiores obcaecati sapiente neque nostrum cum voluptates odit quas labore facilis vero explicabo nisi repellat placeat dignissimos dolorum officiis?
```